# Convergence of an integral involving matrices

Tags: matrices, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

Let $A$ be any positive definite square matrix of size $n$ and $B$ be any symmetric matrix of size $n$. I guess the integral
$$\int_0^\infty e^{-tA}Be^{-tA}~\mathrm{d}t$$
is convergent. I am not sure how to show this. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $X=\int_0^\infty e^{-tA}Be^{-tA}~\mathrm{d}t$ is a form that can be given to the solution of the so-called [**Sylvester equation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation) $XA+AX=B$.

Comment: @JeanMarie I understand that using this, one can say that the integral is convergent. But is there any direct way to show the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $A$ is assumed to be positive definite, the eigenvalues of $e^{-tA}$ are equal to $e^{-t\lambda_j}$, where $\lambda_j$ are the eigenvalues of $A$. Let $\lambda_1$ be the smallest one. Then $e^{-t\lambda_j} \le e^{-t\lambda_1} $
and hence $\|e^{-tA}\| \le  e^{-t\lambda_1} $.

Then the norm of the integrand is bounded by $e^{-2t\lambda_1} \|B\|$, which is an integrable function. Hence the integral in question exists.

Comment: Why does the inequality $\|e^{-tA}\| \le  e^{-t\lambda}$ hold? As per as I know $\|A\|\ge |\lambda|$ for any eigenvalue $\lambda$.

Comment: The question remains the same, why does inequality $\|e^{-tA}\| \le  e^{-t\lambda_1}$ hold?

Comment: For a positive definite matrix, the norm is equal to the largest eigenvalue.